# Enterprise portal, webApp Geometry Server error

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping, error, arcgis-enterprise

I have a web App on an enterprise portal and most people who have access to it (internal and external users) when panning around, zooming or trying to interact with the web App in any way a pop-up error keeps coming up-

[image]

All of my users have 'viewer' roles and the web App doesn't have any fancy widgets.

Has anyone come across this issue before, any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: sorry nobody has replied yet. Can you improve your question by including what version of Enterprise you are running?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that the Utilities/Geometry service is not shared (in Portal) with the group whose members are accessing the WebApp. Check the following:

1. Is the Web App only shared with a Group in Portal?
2. If so, then Share Utilities/Geometry with that Group
3. Is the Web App shared with Public? (which sort of counts as a group in #1 above)
4. If so, then share Utilities/Geometry with Public

[Documentation on Sharing a Portal Item with a group is found here](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/share-items.htm)

The next most likely (very unlikely) answer is that somehow the Geometry Service is not a PortalItem at all, or has been deleted as a Portal Item. In this (rare) case:

1. Create a Portal Item for the existing Utilities/Geometry service
2. Ensure that Portal Item is Shared (as in the above case)

Here is my portal with the Geometry service filtered and Sharing circled:
[image]